# Heap overuse by IBM implementation of SAAJ

Tags: java, soap, heap-memory, saaj

We need to send really huge SOAP messages (multiparts, MTOM), say about 1 or 2 Gigabytes.
Sometimes the process ends up with the following OOM:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2479)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:203)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.channel.OutboundOutputStream.toByteArray(OutboundOutputStream.java:100)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HttpOutboundChannelConnection.prepareHttpRequestHeaders(HttpOutboundChannelConnection.java:2027)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HttpOutboundChannelConnection.sendSOAPRequest(HttpOutboundChannelConnection.java:374)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:745)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:336)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.client.Connection.invokeEngine(Connection.java:970)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.client.Connection.invoke(Connection.java:761)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:223)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:163)
```

As of my understanding, the problem is due to using ByteArrayOutputStream, which looks inappropriate when working with really huge streams.

Following the stacktrace, it requires at least 2 copies of the whole message contents (as byte arrays) in the heap.

So the question, does anyone know a better implementation of SAAJ, by means of heap consumption?
Or may be some workaround for this IBM implementation of SAAJ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that IBM's SAAJ implementation isn't totally braindead, I would expect that it only converts the message to a byte array if HTTP chunking is not enabled and it needs to compute the length of the message before sending it. Therefore, the first thing to do is to make sure that chunking is enabled.

I don't think SAAJ defines a standard way to enable chunking, but you may want to try setting the corresponding HTTP header on the message:

```
soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

Chances are that the SAAJ implementation will honor this.

Comment: I had the same thought about, because chunking is not enabled and Content-Length header is present so far. But yet I have no clear idea how to force chunks there. The protocol declared in request is HTTP1.1, so it should be rather possible.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggestion of what you should try to enable chunking.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it has no effect if we try to set such header directly. Sad, but finally we had to switch from SAAJ to JAX-WS, which handles huge messages correctly.